# Rainmeter: How to concatenate strings

Tags: rainmeter

I am getting data from a broken RSS feed that gives me wrong link. I wanted to fix this link so I made this code:

```
<link.*>(.*)&.*tid(.*)</link>
```

and the link could be like:

```
www.somedomain.com/?value=50&burrrdurrrr;tid=120
```

But the real working link is in this form:

```
www.somedomain.com/?value=50&tid=120
```

The thing that I'm asking is if my measure thing looks like this:

```
[FeedURL]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=Plugins\WebParser.dll
Url=[Feed]
StringIndex=2 ;now I only get www.somedomain.com/?value=50
Substitute=#SubstituteFeed#
```

How am I supposed to concatenate the strings together to complete the url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing rather than `&burrrdurrrr;`, the link has `&amp;`, which is how you have to write `&` in an HTML or XML file.

If that's the case, you just need to [set the `DecodeCharacterReference` option](http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/plugins/webparser#DecodeCharacterReference), as described in this [handy-looking tutorial](http://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/rss-feed-tutorial). Another option mentioned there is [`Substitute`](http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/measures/general-options/substitute), which would be able to strip it out even if it really was `&burrrdurrrr;`.

None of this is a particularly sensible way of dealing with HTML or XML - a much better approach would be a plugin which actually parsed the document structure and let you reference nodes using XPath or CSS rules - but you work with what you've got, I guess. (I've never heard of this "Rainmeter" before, despite its claim to be "the best known and most popular desktop customization program for Windows"; maybe because nobody else calls their program that, instead almost universally using the word "widget"?)